# What is the proper way to archive files using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, directory, compression, zip, archive

My wish is to make a compressed *.zip file of any directory I choose (or allow a user to choose) through Ruby, and I'm not quite sure how to do it. I do know how to create *.zip files, just not compress actual files into an archive. I did some Googling and discovered RubyZip and a couple other resources, but RubyZip is currently in a failing build state and I'm curious on how it is done so that I won't have to fully depend on an outside resource. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "failing build state"? Ultimately, rubyzip is relying on zlib, file utilities and streaming standard libraries in core Ruby, so rubyzip itself is pure Ruby and has nothing to build. If there's an error you may want to paste that. Zipping files and directories is [not straightforward](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/tree/master/lib/zip), so IMO this is actually a great candidate for an external library.

I seem to have no problem, so I'm interested in what your actual error is.

```
$ gem install rubyzip
Fetching: rubyzip-1.1.0.gem (100%) yadayada
```

And using a slightly modified version of the example on the [source homepage](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip), you can zip a directory (recursive) passed at the command line easily:

```
require 'pathname'
require 'zip'

directory = Pathname.new(ARGV.first)
zipfile_name = "#{directory}.zip"

Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  Dir[File.join(directory, '**', '**')].each do |file|
    path = Pathname.new(file)
    zipfile.add(path.relative_path_from(directory), file)
  end
end
```

IMO, the answer in this case is to use a popular library and follow the docs. Rubyzip has had some changes recently, so it's possible that some advice you can find out there is outdated, or there might some issues that require a few tweaks. But the functionality turns out to be a heck of a wheel to reinvent.

Comment: Alright. I just have a couple questions on that response: 1) Is 'pathname' an different gem? 2) If I were to pass in a name that I wanted the directory to be named (e.g. dirname = "backup_#{Time.now}"), how would that be accomplished?

Comment: [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) is part of the Ruby standard library. I'm using it for the `relative_path_from` convenience method. If you wanted to save a zipfile with a timestamp, yeah, you can just set `zipfile_name = "backup_#{Time.now}.zip"`, and you can change the first argument in `zipfile.add` to whatever you'd like to determine where a file is saved in the zip file.